# How to avoid too many open files issue in movipy?

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I am trying to create an mp4 by concatenating some videoclips using moviepy. However, depending on number of clips, I get the error: **`too many open files`**. In the code below two lists are being used where **jpegs** contains all embedded pictures and their corresponding mp3 in **mp3s** list having more than 100 clips.

```
image_main = []
d = 0

for i in range(0,len(jpegs)):

   audio = AudioFileClip(mp3s[i])

   image = (ImageClip(jpegs[i])
        .set_duration(audio.duration)
        .set_audio(audio))

   d  = d + (image.duration / 60.0)
   print(jpegs[i])
   print('TOTAL DURATION: ', d)

   image_main.append(image)
   #del audio.reader
   #del audio
```

As seen in the code snippet above, I tried to add deleting audio (lines commented out) just after being appended. However, this caused another issue in the code below as a result of which I could not create video file.

```
concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(image_main, method="compose", transition=transition)
clip_resized = concat_clip.resize(width=1920)
clip_resized.write_videofile("REDDIT/stupid_TRIAL.mp4", fps=24, threads = 4)
```

Now I have solved the issue by just using a few videos instead of many.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to handle this is to break it down into smaller steps. After you have imported lots of audio/image files, concatenate them and write them to a temp video file. Then close each of the audio files with `audio.close()` (this will automatically close `audio.reader`.

Repeat this process until you have done all of the files, then read the temp video files in and concatenate *those* ones together.